# On Linux Mint, how can I install the font Antiqua for XeLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, latex

In Linux Mint, how can I install the font "Book Antiqua" to my system. Namely, I have the following LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \title{\textbf{Gummi 0.8.0}}
    \author{x}
    \date{}
    
    \addtolength{\topmargin}{-3cm}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{3cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[%
    left=3cm,%
    right=3cm,%
    top=2.5cm,%3
    bottom=2.5cm,%
    headheight=33pt,%
]{geometry}%
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
%\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Antiqua-fontti
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\footheight}{17.99445pt}
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setmainfont{Book Antiqua}
\begin{center}
asijdo

dsad
\end{center}
```

When I tried to compile the document by the command `xelatex demo.tex`, the output was

```
Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid filename `Book Antiqua', contains ' '

! Package fontspec Error: The font "Book Antiqua" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.32 \begin
           {center}
?
```

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: As mentioned in chat, this LaTeX file does not compile as written, and also seems to be rather longer than needed. TeX SE is the place to get TeX questions answered. But before you ask there I recommend you make sure your example compiles, and remove everything from your file that is not necessary to exhibit the problem.

Answer (score -1):

To use a font, it needs to be previously described. Usually, these descriptions come as a package, and the standard package `fontspec` is a nice example of it.

You would need a file with the font itself be available to the document, and add a definition like:

```
\setromanfont{Font Name}[
    Path=./path_relative_to_doc_with_all_files_of_this_font/,
    Extension = .ttf,
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    BoldFont=*-Bold,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic
    ]
```